# Composer not updating modules in windows

Tags: composer

I'm update drupal core using composer with success.

```
composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 9 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading drupal/core (9.4.0 => 9.4.5)
  - Upgrading drupal/core-composer-scaffold (9.4.0 => 9.4.5)
  - Upgrading drupal/core-project-message (9.4.0 => 9.4.5)
  - Upgrading drupal/core-recommended (9.4.0 => 9.4.5)
  - Upgrading drupal/core-vendor-hardening (9.4.0 => 9.4.5)
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.7 => 6.5.8)
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.8.5 => 1.9.0)
  - Upgrading symfony/css-selector (v6.1.0 => v6.1.3)
  - Upgrading symfony/mailer (v5.4.8 => v5.4.11)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 9 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading drupal/core-composer-scaffold (9.4.0 => 9.4.5): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading drupal/core-project-message (9.4.0 => 9.4.5): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading drupal/core-vendor-hardening (9.4.0 => 9.4.5): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.8.5 => 1.9.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.7 => 6.5.8): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading drupal/core (9.4.0 => 9.4.5): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading drupal/core-recommended (9.4.0 => 9.4.5)
  - Upgrading symfony/css-selector (v6.1.0 => v6.1.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/mailer (v5.4.8 => v5.4.11): Extracting archive
    Cleaning: guzzlehttp/psr7
    Cleaning: symfony/css-selector
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Generating autoload files
Hardening vendor directory with .htaccess and web.config files.
44 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
  - Copy [project-root]/.editorconfig from assets/scaffold/files/editorconfig
  - Copy [project-root]/.gitattributes from assets/scaffold/files/gitattributes
  - Copy [web-root]/.csslintrc from assets/scaffold/files/csslintrc
  - Copy [web-root]/.eslintignore from assets/scaffold/files/eslintignore
  - Copy [web-root]/.htaccess from assets/scaffold/files/htaccess
  - Copy [web-root]/example.gitignore from assets/scaffold/files/example.gitignore
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php from assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php
Cleaning installed packages.
```

But i'm trying update modules with composer and it not working. The log show that download and installation is success, but in website reports the module is out of date.

```
composer require drupal/metatag:^1.21

./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/metatag
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking drupal/metatag (1.21.0)
  - Locking drupal/token (1.11.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing drupal/token (1.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing drupal/metatag (1.21.0): Extracting archive
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Generating autoload files
Hardening vendor directory with .htaccess and web.config files.
44 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Cleaning installed packages.
```

After I run /update.php but in /admin/modules/update the module metatag continues in 8.x-1.19, instead 8.x-1.21. I'm using windows.

composer.json

```
{
"name": "drupal/legacy-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.3",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.3",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.3",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9.3",
    "drupal/symfony_mailer": "^1.0@alpha"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "drupal/core-project-message": true,
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true
    }
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "./"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/legacy-project template!               </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you recently update Composer? Seeing the composer.json file would be very useful. I usually vote down Composer questions that do not include it, but I will wait.

Comment: @cilefen sorry, add it.

Comment: drupal/metatag is not in composer.json. How is it installed in the first place?

Comment: @cilefen I installed all site before start use of composer. Maybe this is a cause. How do I configure json to consider the modules installed earlier?

Comment: Composer is configured above to install them into modules/contrib. Is metatag existing in some other place?

Comment: The metatag is installed and running within drupal. In folder modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have two copies of metatag, one, which you installed in `modules/metatag`, which is version 1.19 and another which Composer installs in `modules/contrib/metatag`, which is version 1.21. This is the best answer I can provide given the information you provided in comments.

Comment: They should simply delete the one in the modules/ folder, flush cache and then run updb/update.php again.

Comment: Thanks for help.

the new challenge now is migrate the modules into contrib. Ctools, for example, when incorporated into composer and removed from the /modules folder breaks the site. Probably because of dependencies (required by). Is there a way to make composer store modules directly in the modules folder? Or is this not a good idea?

Comment: The answer to that should be evident from the installer-paths configuration in composer.json.

Comment: OK. I solved it removing modules in /modules, executing composer require and running /update.php. Thanks.